# Implications between $\mathsf{L}=\mathsf{P}$ and $\mathsf{NL}=\mathsf{NP}$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, nondeterminism

If we can prove that  $\mathsf{L}=\mathsf{P}$, does it imply that $\mathsf{NL}=\mathsf{NP}$ ?

I thought it is the case, but I cannot prove it (also for the converse).

Comment: Proving the converse would be pretty hard...

Comment: The converse boils to whether NL=P  implies L=P. This is not necessarily true unless L=NL.

Comment: I posted a related question about the relationships between P vs L, NP vs NL, BPP vs BPL, ⊕P vs ⊕L.  If you're interested, please feel free to take a look.  Thank you!  https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/31073/any-known-connections-between-open-problems-for-time-and-space-p-vs-l-np-vs-nl

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. It is possible that L=P and that P != NP which implies that NL != NP since NL is contained in P.

Comment: I think it would probably be helpful, rather than merely asserting this outright, to give some intuition how this could be. Considering the construction **NP** = **∃P** (i.e. its definition in terms of checking a witness using a polytime algorithm),I can see how one might guess that if **P** = **L**, that we could simply obtain  **NP** = **∃L** = **NL** by substitution. Perhaps some remarks on how the logarithmic limitation on the work tape would help to indicate why this is not the case.