# Any known connections between open problems for time and space: P vs L, NP vs NL, BPP vs BPL, ⊕P vs ⊕L

Tags: space-complexity, logspace, structural-complexity, complexity, probabilistic-complexity

It would be nice to show that $P=L$ implies $NP=NL$.  Or, $NP=NL$ implies $UP=UL$.  Or maybe, $⊕P = ⊕L$ implies $PP = PL$.

Are there any known connections between the problems: P vs L, UP vs UL, NP vs NL, ZPL vs ZPP, RL vs RP, BPP vs BPL, PP vs PL, or ⊕P vs ⊕L?

I just started to learn about probabilistic space complexity classes so for all I know there are known results or maybe this hasn't even been investigated thoroughly.

An incomplete list of results (correct me if any of them are wrong):

(1) $L \subseteq UL \subseteq NL$

(2) $L \subseteq ZPL \subseteq RL \subseteq BPL \subseteq PL$

(3) $RL \subseteq NL \subseteq PL \cap ⊕L$

(4) $PL \cup ⊕L \subseteq NC^2 \subseteq P$

One connection: if any of these problems have a positive answer, then we get $NC^2 = P$, $PSPACE = EXPTIME$, and $AL \neq AP$ where it is well known that $AL = P$ and $AP = PSPACE$.

For example, suppose that we have $PP=PL$.  Then, we get $PL = NC^2 = P = PP$.  And, $NC^2 = P$ implies $PSPACE = EXPTIME$.  Further, we can't have $AL = AP$.  Otherwise, we would get $P = PSPACE = EXPTIME$ which violates the time hierarchy theorem.

Any corrections, ideas, thoughts, results, or references are appreciated.  Thank you for reading!  :)

Comment: Where are you getting NL = ZPL from? That seems unlikely to be known (or true).

Comment: There are two extant definitions of randomized log space classes, depending on whether you also demand the running time to be polynomial or not. The uninteresting definition implies $\mathrm{ZPL}=\mathrm{RL}=\mathrm{NL}$, the interesting one does not. It seems that the notation in the list mixes up these two conventions.

Comment: @HuckBennett Wikipedia says, "It is known that NL is equal to ZPL, the class of problems solvable by randomized algorithms in logarithmic space and unbounded time, with no error."

Comment: Link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NL_%28complexity%29#Containments

Comment: I see now.  Thanks!  I will fix it so that ZPL above means logspace and polynomial time.  :)

Comment: @MichaelWehar Is $NC=PSPACE$ or $RNC=PSPACE$ possible?

Comment: @Problem I could be mistaken, but I think $NC = PSPACE$ would imply $P = EXPTIME$ which violates the time hierarchy theorem.  In other words, I think that $NC \neq PSPACE$.  I'm not sure about $RNC$ though.  I think these are neat questions!!  :)